# NgRx: How to load InjectionToken value into a metareducer

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I wish to provide a dynamic NGRX storage name, by loading the env name from the application config file. It`s easy for the rest of the application components and services, but it doesn`t work for the metaReducer.

I have this in the app.module
[image]

And that is the MetaReducer content
[image]

Is it possible to inject the **API_BASE_ENV** into the reducer`s name?

Answer (score 1):

you can't inject an `Injection Token` or use [Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) in general in a Reducer since it is not an angular service but a mere js function

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution, by using the @Injectiable class as Rachid suggested it, by using the same properties from the app.module in the providers' area
[image]